# Compute the minimum value of $a^n + b^n + c^n$ subject to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1 $

Tags: inequality, optimization

> Assume that $a,b,c$  are non-negative real numbers and $n$ is a natural number $n \ge 3$. What is $f(n)=$ the minimum value of $a^n + b^n + c^n$ ?

I find ;

$$f(3) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\qquad f(4) = \frac{1}{3}$$

then I guess

$$f(n) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right)^n \times 3 $$ 
Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power mean inequality gives $$\sqrt[n]{\frac{a^n+b^n+c^n}{3}} \geq \sqrt[2]{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}=\sqrt{\frac13}$$

with equality if $a=b=c$. Hence the minimal value is $3\left(\frac13\right)^{n/2}$, which is attained if $a=b=c=\left(\frac13\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Unless  I am mistaken, equality is attained for $a=b=c=\left(\frac13\right)^{1/2}$, to satisfy $a^2 +b^2 +c^2=1$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that was what I meant. Then each of $a^n,b^n,c^n$ are equal to $\left(\frac13\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: The power mean is good ! , thank you .

Comment: I vote this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is true. First, $f(n)=a^n+b^n+(1-(a^2+b^2))^{\frac{n}{2}}$, calculate its derivative w.r.t. $a$, one obtains it has the minima $a=\sqrt{\frac{1-b^2}{2}}$. Inserting this into $f(n)$, we obtain $f(n)=2(\frac{1-b^2}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}+b^n$, now calculate its derivative w.r.t. $b$, you obtain it has the minima $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Now one concludes that $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\min f(n)=3^{\frac{2-n}{2}}$.

Comment: What about the intersection of the sphere with the boundary of the nonnegative orthant?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it does not matter, the function is also regular including the bdry points. You can consider the left or right limits in this case.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the convexity is not to be assumed, it is given or not if the function is given. It is also not necessary to consider the convexity, you just let the derivative larger or less then zero, and you find the result.

Answer (score 2):

Set $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (a, b, c)$. Applying [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) to $(x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2)$ and $ (1, 1, 1)$
with 
$$
 p = \frac n2 \, , \quad q = \frac{n}{n-2}
$$
gives
$$
 1 = \sum_{k=1}^3 x_k^2 \cdot 1 \le \left( \sum_{k=1}^3 x_k^n \right)^{\frac 2n} \cdot  \left( \sum_{k=1}^3 1 \right)^{\frac {n-2}{n}} \\
 =  \left( \sum_{k=1}^3 x_k^n \right)^{\frac 2n} \cdot  3 ^{\frac {n-2}{n}}
$$
which implies
$$
 x_1^n + x_2^n + x_3^n\ge \left(\frac 13 \right)^{\frac {n-2}{2}} = 
 \frac{3}{(\sqrt 3)^n}
$$
and equality holds for $x_1  = x_2 = x_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$,
so this is the minimum value, as you conjectured.

Comment: Holder's inequality is good for a proof. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is true. Once one has proved that the minimum is achieved for $a=b=c$ (which can be done for example with standard Lagrange multiplier metohd), then the value is easily obtained:
$$
\min (f)=3 a^n,\;1=3a^2\Rightarrow \min (f)=3^{1-n/2}
$$

Comment: Thank you. How about the proof ?